# PDO: check for updated or inserted record using mysql INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Using PDO / PHP and MySQL, how can I check if a record was inserted or updated when I use an `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement?

I have seen a solution using `mysql_affected_rows()` for PHP, but I am looking for a way I can use with PDO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use [PDO::exec()](http://docs.php.net/pdo.exec) the return value will be 1 if the row has been inserted and 2 if the row has been updated.

If you're using a prepared statement and PDOStatement::execute() the same is true for [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://docs.php.net/pdostatement.rowcount)